# openshift database and data directory

Tags: openshift, openshift-cartridge

I was looking at a README file that raised some questions about database persistence on Openshift.

> Note: Every time you push, everything in your remote repo dir gets recreated
>         please store long term items (like an sqlite database) in the OpenShift
>         data directory, which will persist between pushes of your repo.
>         The OpenShift data directory is accessible relative to the remote repo
>         directory (../data) or via an environment variable OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR.

https://github.com/ryanj/nodejs-custom-version-openshift/blob/master/README#L24

However, I could find no confirmation of this on the Openshift website. Is this README out of date? I'd rather not test this, so it would be much appreciated if anyone had any firsthand knowledge they'd be willing to share.

Comment: Up voted just for the typo in the question title, and I am childish :)

Comment: Ahh man! That's a bummer lol :(

Comment: Yeah, thankfully it was edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, that readme file is up to date regarding SQLite. All gears have SQLite installed on them. Data should be stored in the persistent storage directory on your gear. This does not apply to MySQL/MongoDB/PostgreSQL as those databases are add-on cartridges pre-configured to use persistent storage, whereas SQLite is simply installed and available for use.

See the first notice found in the OpenShift Origin documentation here: https://docs.openshift.org/origin-m4/oo_cartridge_guide.html

Specifically:

> **Cartridges and Persistent Storage**: Every time you push, everything in
>   your remote repo directory is recreated. Store long term items (like
>   an sqlite database) in the OpenShift data directory, which will
>   persist between pushes of your repo. The OpenShift data directory can
>   be found via the environment variable `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`.

The official OpenShift Django QuickStart shows the design pattern you should follow for adding SQLite to your application via the deploy action hook. See: https://github.com/openshift/django-example/blob/master/.openshift/action_hooks/deploy

Comment: This wouldn't apply to a `postgres` cartridge right?